# Mixed Linear Integer Programming using Coin-OR CBC

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, coin-or-cbc

I'm using CBC on the Windows command line for solving a Mixed Integer Linear Programming problem which works out pretty well as it solves the problem in a reasonable amount of time.

However, I can't figure out how to get CBC to print the values of the variables that forms the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand [this](http://www.coin-or.org/Cbc/cbcuserguide.html#firstexample) example from the [CBC User Guide](http://www.coin-or.org/Cbc/cbcuserguide.html) correctly, you get the solution variables by using the `const double * CbcModel::bestSolution()` function.

Additionally, you should be able to identify the context of each variable by using these functions:

```
bool isBinary(int colIndex) const
bool isContinuous(int colIndex) const
bool isInteger(int colIndex) const
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
solu sol.txt
```

This will write the solution to a file named sol.txt. The variables that you don't see in the file take the value zero.